SMS in journey builder
Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and for your support on the mobile SMS question.
The use case: there is a landing page (LP) through which we can opt-in to receive SMS. We enter a journey, and day by day we receive a series of SMS messages, and we need to capture the responses.
I need to capture the responses in a Data Extension (DE).
However, I see that it is not possible to use Mobile Connect SMS templates in Journey Builder (based on the few threads I've read here).
My question : With an SMS activity, is it possible to engage in a conversation and captures responses? :
Your help would be much appreciated.
Again, thank you

You would need to configure a next keyword in your SMS activity in the Journey and have a text response message for that keyword in Mobile Connect.
Then the text response in Mobile Connect can be used as a workaround to capture their response.
E.g. you have a text response message with configured keyword REPLY in Mobile Connect, define the response content something like this:
%%[
var @response
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]
/* Capture SMS response */
UpsertData('Your DE name', 1, 'MobileNumber', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'Response', @response)

]%%
Thank you, we have received your response!

While your SMS activity in the journey is configured with the next key word is REPLY at "Advanced Options" tab.
The SMS content for this Journey SMS activity should guide them to text to your MC short/long code with the REPLY keyword. E.g.
Text 'REPLY Your_Response' to 'MC short/long code'.

This was really useful, thanks a lot!
